# ubuntu 16.04 Can't open virtualbox 5.2 machine

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, vagrant

When I try to run homestead-7 virtual machine I got this error

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

also

```
The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
```

I tried to run

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

I got this

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
Bus error (core dumped)
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
Bus error (core dumped)
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
Bus error (core dumped)
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot at UEFI.

Comment: where is secure boot?

Comment: At the UEFI settings. And if you don't know what that is either (hint: UEFI is what replaced BIOS for almost all PC from a decade or so ago) you seriously need an update, i.e., you need to acquire basic knowledge about the hardware you have in order to to able to do the advanced tasks you committed yourself to, like virtualization.